# How action bar behave on FragmentTransaction replace() and FragmentTransaction add()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using fragment, to display two screen in my application.
Each Fragment has its own set of menu layout for action bar buttons .

On commit for a fragment using FragmentTransaction replace()  method, it works fine by inflating menu layout respective to each Fragment.

Where as

On commit for a fragment using FragmentTransaction add()  method, it inflate menu layout of Both Fragment.

How this add() method of FragmentTransaction changes the behavior.

It is possible to call add() method of FragmentTransaction and inflate menu layout respective to visible Fragment only ?

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer, i should call menu.clear() ever time i add any fragment inside onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

}
```